# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kiv_deps.sd12==0.1.* (from versions: none)

Tags: python, kivy

That is the error I am getting when im trying to install kivy

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kiv_deps.sd12==0.1.*
```

That error too, does somoane know a fix?

Comment: You tried `pip install kivy-deps.sdl2`?

Comment: @JamiuShaibu im gone try now!

Comment: @JamiuShaibu it said Requirement already satisfied kivy-deps.sdl2 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.4.5)